# How to treat resources separately in resource pool (annylogic)?

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I am trying to develop a model in anylogic that will consider machine breakdown. So I have basically 3 equal machines that will be working in three different lines. For that, I have created a resource pool with all the three machines inside and also a probability of failure/repair. 
The problem is that whenever a failure happens, all three machines stop working. Is there a way to say that not necessarily all three machines will break simultaneously? if yes, is it possible to know specifically which one broke? It is very important for me to also know the duration of the breakdown, because it will affect the response of my system.

Comment: you probably have in the resource initial time to failure equal to a constant (in which case they all fail the same time)... are you doing that?... also in the initial time to failure you have access to the unit so you can customize your times to failure unit by unit

Comment: Hello Felipe! Thank you very much for your answer. I'm actually using a distribution for the initial/ consequent failures (I just set a random Weibull distribution at the moment for both the variables). But, even thought, it seams through my simulation, that all of my machines are stopping at the same time, is that possible? In addition, how do I know which exact unit had a failure? The machines (resources) that I'm considering are in the last process of my production line. Therefore, if they fail, I need to know the amount of buffer I will need to produce to achieve production goals.